# How do I convert JSON to HTML through JQUERY?

Tags: jquery, html, json, undefined

I'm trying to parse some JSON data into a webpage.  I keep receiving an "undefined" error where the JQUERY variable should be displayed.  I have scanned through previous solutions; unfortunately, they are over my head since I'm a newbie.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my JSON contents:

```
[{"v_avg2":"-1.93","v_max2":"9.40","v_min2":"-12.30","v_std2":"7.42","s_avg2":"-0.18","s_max2":"7.87","s_min2":"-9.18","s_std2":"5.47","alpha_avg2":"-1.75","alpha_max2":"1.53","alpha_min2":"-4.76","VCAGR":"-26.542465909469826","SCAGR":"-4.004316028237165"}]
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>
    </head>
<body>

<h2>Testing HTML/JSON</h2>

<div>
    <span id="nums"></span>
</div>

<script>
fetch('./php/beta0472019.php')
.then(function (response){
    return response.json();
})
.then(function (json){
    console.log(json);
    var vavg = json.v_avg2;
    $('#nums').html('VIOG Mean: <span style="float:right;">' +vavg+ '</span><br>');         
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated for this beginner.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json[0].v_avg2` since it is an array